# How is java byte code executed since all operating systems don't preinstalled JRE(JAVA RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT) that include java virtual machine

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, bytecode

How is it possible to say that java is portable if the JRE not available in all operating systems which contains JVM that help execute the byte code.

Comment: Little gnomes do it for you.

Comment: The same way, C++ is called portable despite not every operating system comes with a pre-installed C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

When we say java is portable or write once run anywhere that means the bycode is platform independent but jvm or jre is not platform independent.

And bytecode does not run directly on the underlying OS but it runs on jvm.

That's why java is portal or platform independent. But jvm or jre is highly platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

A Java Runtime Environment must be invoked to run the bytecode. Java comes pre-installed on many operating system distributions these days, but users can also install their own. You cannot run Java bytecode without a virtual machine runtime environment.

Java applications are "portable" in that they will run on a JVM that is installed on any operating system or chip architecture, but actually distributing a Java application to clients on many systems can be a pain. The best practice is for developers to ship their preferred version of a JRE with the software so that they have control over the environment and don't have to rely on the client having a properly configured JRE installed on their machine. The motivation is similar to apps that use a containerized browser (like Spotify, Slack, and many others) shipping an entire web browser with their native applications.